# Actionscript 3 ScrollPane content not updating Scrollbars

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a scroll pane added, then i add a custom movie clip exported within a sprite but when i do all this then hit the update command the ScrollPane never updates and no Scrollbars are displayed.

The code is below:

```
 function doneLoad(e:Event):void {
        trace("doneload");
        var bm:Bitmap = e.target.content as Bitmap;
        bm.smoothing = true;
        bm.x = 20;
        bm.y = 20;
        bm.width = 80;
        bm.height = 80;



        shape1.addChild(getTextField("Helvetica",12,"0x31b1e1","left","Name:",120,10));
        shape1.addChild(getTextField("Helvetica",12,"0xcccccc","left",user.name,120,28));

        shape1.addChild(bm);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,doneLoad);
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,loadingError); 
        sql.removeEventListener(SQLEvent.POST_COMPLETE,dataPostResponse);

        scroll = new ScrollPane();
        scroll.width = 320;
        scroll.height = 300;
        scroll.x = 0;
        scroll.y = 140;
        scroll.verticalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.AUTO;
        //scroll.verticalScrollPolicy = ScrollPolicy.ON;
        shape1.addChild(scroll);

        //var content:DisplayObject = new DisplayObject();
        content = new Sprite();

        var dd:mc_countryDP = new mc_countryDP();
        content.addChild(dd);
        dd.x = 0;
        dd.y = 280;

        //scroll.addChild(content);
        scroll.source = content;

        loader = null;

        mc_user.visible = true;
        //content.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        scroll.update();
    }
```

Comment: scrollpane updates when you assign a new content which you do here. The call to update() is irrelevant in that case and is not the source of your problem. The content you try to add is probably not big enough to force scrollbar to appear. Try with a bigger content.

Comment: i set the scroll height to 100 to see what would happen, the scroll pane showed the vertical scrollbar but could not find the content thats added to the scroll.content

Comment: the content is there when i set the scroll height to 300

Comment: you explicitly set the content inside the added content to a y of 280 making it disappear. You are using a not so good Flash IDE component (I'm guessing) and those are easily confused. Do not set the y of your inner content to a high value. Easiest way to fix all those problem is to draw a non visible rectangle covering all inner content directly on your Sprite content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, you do not need to update the scrollpane. You only need to update the scrollpane if you change something about the source that is attached to it. When you first attach a source it will automatically update the scrollpane to the new size.

As for the positioning, when you add something to something else, then the postion (x,y) will be relative to that. In other words, if I have sprite A, which is positioned on the stage at (100,100), and I attach sprite B to it, and then I set the position for B to (10,10), then sprite B will appear as though it is at position (110,110) to the stage. This is because it is position (10,10) in reference to sprite A which happens to already be offset from the stage's origin by (100,100). So when you attach your object to "content" and then set its y to 280, you are setting it to 280 in reference to where the content is, which in this case is inside of a scrollpane.

Lastly, you should consider using the inherited functions setSize and move, instead of setting the x/y and width/height manually. I doubt there are any negative effects of doing it the way you have it, but I suppose better safe than sorry.

Hope that clears it up, though maybe that was too wordy.